# how to fix context cannot be resolved or is not a field?

Tags: android

i am trying to enable alarmManager and also my broadcastreceiver through another service everytime i receive an SMS but the problem is, i am getting this error on the third line -**context cannot be resolved or is not a field**. i have already replaced all the `this` with `context`. what am i missing?

```
private void freeze(Context context) {
    // ENABLE MyReceiver SERVICE
            ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(IncomingSmsDetectorReceiver.context,
                    FreezerReceiver.class);
            PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
            pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
            // --//
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, FreezerReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            long recurring = (500); // tweak here
            am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, Calendar.getInstance()
                    .getTimeInMillis(), recurring, sender);
}
```

Comment: Simply pass _context_ instead of _IncomingSmsDetectorReceiver.context_

Comment: Here _ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(IncomingSmsDetectorReceiver.context,
                    FreezerReceiver.class);_

Comment: Where does _freeze()_ method call?

Comment: Here only _context_ not _context.context_

Comment: Okay Sure. NP ! Is it done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `context` instead of `context.context`

Comment: If you want to call in service then you should use _Service_ class in which your method continuous call. And if you want to stop service automatically after your task has been completed then you should use _IntentService_

Comment: Then you should register your broadcast receiver in to your main activity class

Comment: Check this http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/11/introduction-to-services-in-android.html

Comment: hmm i actually wanted another class inside my receiver. which i can call instead of calling the activity

Comment: i asked a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36276259/how-to-make-a-device-freeze

Answer (score 1):

```
 ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(IncomingSmsDetectorReceiver.context,
                    FreezerReceiver.class);
```

change this to

```
 ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(),
                    FreezerReceiver.class);
```

**getApplicationContext()** will return you the **Context** your are in. I hope this was helpful. ThankYou

Comment: From every where in entire app he will able to getApplicationContext()?

Comment: What do you mean where in app??? getApplicationContext() is a method which will return you the current context. The context may be an Activity or homeScreen etc.

Comment: plus one for the effort, but he answered first.

Comment: i asked a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36276259/how-to-make-a-device-freeze

Answer (score 0):

You shoud use **getApplicationContext()** method whenever you need context of the current activity as its return type is Context.

You can also use `this` keyword in the argument like :

```
ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(this,FreezerReceiver.class);
```

But,this is applicable only if you are writing it in `IncomingSmsDetectorReceiver` class.

Comment: i asked a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36276259/how-to-make-a-device-freeze

Answer (score 0):

You should save MainActivity's context in to a public variable to use it in broadcast.

```
public Context mContext;
mContext = getActivity();
```

Modify your code

```
ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(mContext ,
                    FreezerReceiver.class);
            PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
```

Hope it will fix your issue.