# How to make a device freeze?

Tags: android

This is a bit weird question, however, I need this for my project. I am trying to simulate "*out of memory*" effect by calling the activity in its own onCreate (this calls the activity infinitely) which works perfectly fine

```
// launch this activity again and again making the device freeze and
    // reboot
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.systemmanager",
            "com.android.systemmanager.FreezeScreen1"));
    startActivity(intent);
```

but the problem here is that I don't want to use any classes. I want to do this in the onReceive of my Broadcast Receiver instead. How can I accomplish this given that there will not be any classes to call?

Is there any other method to make the device freeze?

also i am using AlarmManager to call my onReceive every second. this would help speeding up the freezing process

Comment: Creating `bitmaps` in a loop will work.

Comment: Get 10 really huge images which exceeds 3 MB in size. Use them in frame animation. It will throw OutOfMemory error while building Animation object.

Comment: Or just allocate arrays of 1 million integers (eating 4MB at a time).  Keep a reference to them so they can't be garbage collected.

Comment: just put full hd image like 10mb into nodpi or load it with image loader without resize

Comment: Dude i just said i want to make the app as tiny as possible. 10 mb is gigantic

Comment: i already suggest load from web to try loader or picasso without resize image surely you will achieve i faced that with 22mb size image 4650*2346 from server

Comment: @AjayPandya i hope that comment was a joke.

Comment: Nope that will surely work but need Web service and image like that you will surely get OOM

Comment: i want this to work locally and offline

Comment: can a rapid frame animation of two tiny (2kb) images do the job? if we call this method every second

Comment: Emily, You can take only one big image and repeat the same for every frame. Simple :)

Comment: make a never-ending while loop? Worked for me and I did not even wanna do it :D `int i; while(true){ i++;}` or something should work

Comment: vucko, will this make my app force close eventually? because apps force close when out of memory for a long period

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be this:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
     final int TOTAL_BITMAPS = 1000; //any large number would work.
     for(int i=0; i<TOTAL_BITMAPS; i++){
          Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.large_image); // load a large bitmap from drawable..
          bitmapArray.add(bitmap);
     }
}
```

Comment: hey if the app force closes, my app will be caught. will it force close?

Comment: app will be closed by `android` system due to out of memory error. But if you broadcast new event, it will run again.

Answer (score 0):

Create this method

```
private void stackOverFlow()
{
    this.stackOverFlow();
}
```

Then call this method whenever you want your app to freeze.